# What are the better ways to code this nested conditional structure?

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements, nested-if

I would use R as an example:

```
# x is an object
# condA(x), condB(x) and condC(x) evaluate x and return TRUE or FALSE
# The conditions must be evaluated in the following orders.
#   For e.g., when validating for an random object being a number larger than 5,
#   you always need to evaluate whether it is numeric first,
#   only after which can you evaluate whether it is larger than 5.
#   Trying to evaluate both at once will cause an error if it is non-numeric.
# process1() and process2() are two different procedures
# modify1() is a modifier for x
if (condA(x)) {
  if (condB(x)) {
    x %<>% modify1
    if (condC(x)) {
      process1()
    } else {
      process2()
    }
  } else {
    process2()
  }
} else {
  if (cond(C)) {
    process1()
  } else {
    process2()
  }
}
```

This way I need to specify each of the processes more than once, and repeat the chunk of evaluating condC(x), which I feel clumsy doing so. Any suggestion for a more elegant way of coding this structure, so that I need to mention each of process1() and process2() only once, without disrupting the order of evaluations as stated in the above code?

---

**More information:**
I suppose it is a general question, but maybe an example can facilitate the discussion... Let's say a modification is needed if `condB(x)` evaluates `TRUE`.

- `condA()` is `is.character()`
- `condB()` is `exists()`
- `condC()` is `is.data.table()`
- `modify1()` is `get()`

So, if `x` is a character, it is supposed to represent an object name, whose existence is then verified, and then converted to the object's pointer. If `x` is not a character, it is supposed to point to the target object. The target object (which is pointed by `x`) is then verified to see if it is a `data.table`. If yes, `process1()`, otherwise `process2()`.

Comment: What you’ve written is totally fine. Technically it may be possible to reduce some redundancy but the current setup is plenty readable and presumably works.

Comment: Question, why not to use duck typing? you can use `tryCatch()`. Test if x is bigger than 5, if it's not numeric the `tryCatch()` will deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

Long version:

```
boolean A = condA(x);
boolean B = false;
boolean C = false;

if (A) {
    B = condB(x);
}

if (A && B || !A) {
    C = condC(x);
}

if (C) {
    process1();
} else {
    process2();
}
```

Short version:

```
boolean A = condA(x);
boolean B = A && condB(x);
boolean C = (A && B || !A) && condC(x);

if (C) {
    process1();
} else {
    process2();
}
```

PS: I am not sure about R language but the above is my idea.

Comment: The short version does not work. The second line will return an error if A is false, since condB(x) can only be evaluated when A is true. The long version is acceptable in this case.

Comment: In short version, second line, `condB(x)` shall only run when A is true. If A is false, `condB(x)` will be ignored and B is assigned to false. That is for C language, maybe R language evaluates both operands of `&&` operator. Even if the first operand is false.